# simple way for parsing/manipulation html in php

Tags: php, string, parsing, dom

i'm writing a datagrid widget which uses lots of dropdown boxes, eg. having this markup:

```
<select name="users">
    <option value="1">Mark</option>
    <option value="2">Jen</option>
    <option value="3">John</option>
</select>
```

i've stored this markup into a variable and i'm wondering if it's possible to set the current value through php? so it's classical string manipulation - but i dont' want to use a library like simple dom parser.. any ideas?
thanks

Comment: SimpleXML or DocumentDOM would fit this PERFECT. Why for heavens sake don't use it >.<

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[1] = 'Mark';
$array[2] = 'Jen';
$array[3] = 'John';
$select = "<select>\n";
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    $select .= "\t<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>\n";
}
$select .= "</select>\n";
echo $select;
```

Output:

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>Mark</option>
    <option value='2'>Jen</option>
    <option value='3'>John</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way, might be to make a function that parses the dropdown for you with a supplied array of options and a second parameter which indicates which one is selected by default.

However, you can also use `str_replace()` to find a row with a certain value and add the `selected` attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean,

```
$template1 = '<select name="users">
                 <option value="1">Mark</option>
                 <option value="2">Jen</option>
                 <option value="3">John</option>
              </select>';
```

And then in the code you use to build the HTML page

```
<div><?php echo $template1; ?></div>
```

OR

```
echo '<div>' . $template1 . '</div>';
```

Comment: no i actually mean adding the "selected" attribute to one of the option elements using php

Comment: @Fuxi Are you getting these names from a daatbase or is the hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Tho, `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML` would fit this perfect, here goes your solution:

```
$selected = 'Option 1';
$options  = array('Option 1', 'Test', 'Blargh', 'Lazr');

$select = "<select name='select1'>\n";
foreach ($option as $key => $val)
    $select = "<option value='{$key}'";
    if ($val === $selected) {
        $select .= " selected='selected'";
    }
    $select .= ">{$val}</option>\n";
}

$select .= "</select>\n";

echo $select;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to re-output the HTML, it's very easy to have a preselected value in an understandable array (the value is the key, and the text is the value of the `$select` KVP):

```
<?php
    $select = array(
        'mark' => 'Mark',
        'jen'  => 'Jen',
        'john' => 'John'
    );
    $preSelected = 'jen';

    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . ($key == $preSelected ? ' selected="SELECTED"' : '') . '>' . $value . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

[**CODEPAD DEMO**](http://codepad.org/8Qw8MGNm)

Output (with indentation):

```
<select>
    <option value="mark">Mark</option>
    <option value="jen" selected="SELECTED">Jen</option>
    <option value="john">John</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you would like to do?

```
function renderSelector($attr=array(),$options=array(),$selected=''){
    if(@count($attr))
        foreach($attr as $k=>$v) $attr[$k] = $k.'="'.htmlentities($v).'"';
    if(@count($options))
        foreach($options as $k=>$v) $options[$k] = '<option value="'.htmlentities($k).'" '.(($k==$selected)?'selected':'').'>'.$v.'</option>';

    return $str = '<select '.implode(' ',$attr).'>'.implode('',$options).'</select>';
}

echo renderSelector(
        $attr=array('name'=>'city'),
        $options=array('NY'=>'Newyork','TK'=>'Tokyo','3'=>'London'),
        $selected='TK'
     );
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/0jgW52KZ)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do something like jQuery's `$('option[value=2]').attr('selected', true)`. PHP itself does not understand any markup you store in a string variable. It is only possible with DOM parser.

```
    $template = '<select name="users">
             <option value="1">Mark</option>
             <option value="2">Jen</option>
             <option value="3">John</option>
          </select>';
    $select = simplexml_load_string($template1);
    $selectedValue = "2";
    foreach ($select->children() as $option) {
        if ($option->attributes()->value == $selectedValue) {
            $option->addAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }
    $template = $select->asXML();
```